# Why all command in bash are in lowercase?

Tags: linux, bash

Is there are any convention/agreement about bash commands/scripts naming?

Especially about user-defined commands/scripts.

Comment: By convention, executable binaries tend to be in lower-case.

Comment: [tag:bash] [built-in commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) are all lowercase or `.`, `:`, `[`, `[[`

Comment: @closevoters Why the "primarily opinion-based" close-votes?  Are POSIX guidelines really to be considered as mere opinions? ;-)

Comment: This is so you don't have to use the shift key.  Very ergonomic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [POSIX shell guidelines for utility syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02):

> Guideline 2:
>   Utility names should include lowercase letters (the lower character classification) and digits only from the portable character set.

Answer (score 2):

All standard command tend to be lower-case (with `X` and a few related utilities being the only notable exceptions that come to mind, but these are seldom invoked from the command line directly). This is quite obviously convenient: a lower-case character is just one keystroke while uppercase takes two at the same time and thus is much more cumbersome to type. This is somewhat alleviated by tab completion but nonetheless, using upper case in shell commands stands out and doesn't fit the UNIX conventions too well.